# Can I create a variable that saves the result of the formula?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is an example code where I set a range equal to a string variable, and then save a file name based on the formulas result.

```
Dim vFormula3 As String

'Set up formula into string variable
vFormula3 = "=INDEX($A$7:$AZ$7,MATCH(" & Chr(34) & "Voyage Number" & Chr(34) & ",$A$6:$AZ$6,0))"


'Then Put formula into a cell range
'Set sheet range here if needed
Range("A3") = vFormula3

'Save code goes here
    'blah blah blah save files.
```

Is it possible to instead rewrite the formula so that I set my variable (eg vFormula1) to instead be the result of the formula?

Is there a `Dim vFormula as Formula` approach I could take?

Comment: @jeeped, just a small point, it wasn't actually tmit's question, but tmit's answer to the question you linked to. (Just in case that prompts you to answer the other one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234154/conditionally-auto-name-excel-file-using-vba), look into the [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx). Alternately, a more direct method might be the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx).

You are missing parent worksheet references in your formula; this is not a good idea when using any method of evaluating a formula within VBA are the parent references may be lost due to a roving [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
Dim vFormula3 As String, vResult As Variant

vFormula3 = "INDEX('Sheet One'!$A$7:$AZ$7, " & _
            "MATCH(""Voyage Number"", 'Sheet One'!$A$6:$AZ$6, 0))"
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(vFormula3)
vResult = Application.Evaluate(vFormula3)
Debug.Print vResult

'HLOOKUP is a better formula for this
With Worksheets("Sheet One")
    Debug.Print Application.HLookup("Voyage Number", .Range("A6:AZ7"), 2, False)
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.HLookup("Voyage Number", .Range("A6:AZ7"), 2, False)
    vResult = Application.HLookup("Voyage Number", .Range("A6:AZ7"), 2, False)
    Debug.Print vResult
End With
```

Note that quotes within quoted string need to be doubled up.

I've offered an alternate formula using the [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a). It seems to be better suited to what you are trying to do.

The `Debug.Print` results go to the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx) (tap [Ctrl]+G to show).